# Redirecting Output on Child Process to Parent Process - Powershell

Tags: powershell

i have powershell process and I am calling Start-Process or System.Diagnostic.Process to start a child process as a different user (to get the other-user environment variables)

I tried with redirectoutput but it does not work. Below is the code

```
    $process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $startinfo = New-Object "System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo"

    $startinfo.FileName = "powershell"
    $startinfo.UserName = $user
    $startinfo.Password = $pass
    $startinfo.Arguments = $arguments        
    $startinfo.UseShellExecute = $False
    $startinfo.RedirectStandardInput = $True

    $process.StartInfo = $startinfo
    $process.Start() | Out-Null
    $process.WaitForExist()
    $output = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
```

Also I am trying to run this process as Minimized or Hidden but it does not work.

Any help will be really appreciated
Regards
Ajax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function that'll do what you want:

```
function Invoke-PSCommandAsUser
{
    param(
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$cred, 
        [System.String]$command
    );

    $psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

    $psi.RedirectStandardError = $True
    $psi.RedirectStandardOutput = $True

    $psi.UseShellExecute = $False
    $psi.UserName = $cred.UserName
    $psi.Password = $cred.Password

    $psi.FileName = (Get-Command Powershell).Definition
    $psi.Arguments = "-Command $command"

    $p = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)
    $p.WaitForExit()

    Write-Output $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
}
```

According to MSDN you won't be able to run this hidden if you use Process.Start as the mechanism

> If the UserName and Password properties of the StartInfo instance are
>   set, the unmanaged CreateProcessWithLogonW function is called, which
>   starts the process in a new window even if the CreateNoWindow property
>   value is true or the WindowStyle property value is Hidden.
>   - [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I have never seen such a crystal clear explanation. I am really thankful to you I will immediately try this out. Once again really appreciated :-)

Comment: Hi, Do you know how to successfully pass an arguments array I am trying to pass this "[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::SetValue('HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment','$keyVar','$valueVar','$regType')" for 3 times in the arguments array.but i get a Exception