# Monitor other process's output in Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, events, process, powershell-2.0, stdout

In Powershell 2.0, I am starting a cmd.exe process in a new window using the following:

```
Start-Process cmd.exe "/k proc.cmd"
```

Is there a way to monitor and react to this process's standard output in realtime (e.g. executing a command when the process outputs "Completed") without hiding its console output?

Comment: This might be useful: [redirecting-output-on-child-process-to-parent-process-powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323922/redirecting-output-on-child-process-to-parent-process-powershell) but it looks like the answer to that question does wait for the process to finish before reading standard output...

Comment: Thanks, you are right, the answer does wait for the process to finish.  I updated my question to specify that I need to monitor the output in realtime since the process never ends on its own

Comment: Unfortunately PSv2 doesn't have `Register-ObjectEvent` which can be used to "listen" to standard output/error events from a running process... I guess that's an answer that can be written another day.

Comment: @CharlieJoynt You are right.  Unfortunately I can't install Powershell 3.0 since the script may be distributed to other computers (That come with 2.0) over time.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `start-process` - you will see the output real time in your active console. If you need it this way, then

- run your line inside job
- use loop to periodically (for instance every 1s) get the jobs output via `receive-job`.

---

**EDIT**

This is the sample script that demonstrates what you want

```
$j = start-job { while(1) { Get-Random; sleep 1 } }
while($j.State -eq 'Running') {
   $out = Receive-Job -Job $j
   $out
   if ($out -like '*44*') { break }
   sleep 1
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I need to start the process in a new window and react to its output.  I've tried using Start-Job but it makes the new process run in the background (Meaning no new window is created).

Comment: You need to use `receive-job` to get the job output. Then you can react to it - you don't need a window for that

Comment: Starting it in a new window was a requirement but I may just wrap the batch command into another powershell script and use this.  I will test it tomorrow morning and update.  Thanks.

Comment: What kind of requirement is that ? :)

Comment: You can do it in another window too, its entirely different script tho.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't wrap the batch command into another powershell script and use your solution, since the reaction to the output needs to happen in the main script (Which must spawn a new window for the process)