# Run app using powershell as admin and get output of child process

Tags: windows, powershell, console, pipe

Recently I ran into an interesting topic. I need to run a powershell command as Administrator

```
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process PowerShell 
-Verb RunAs -Args $command -PassThru -Wait"
```

and get stdout of this command.
Sadly, it gives me only process object.

I tries methods described here:

- [Redirecting Output on Child Process to Parent Process - Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323922/redirecting-output-on-child-process-to-parent-process-powershell)
- [Capturing standard out and error with Start-Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761888/capturing-standard-out-and-error-with-start-process)
- [Powershell: Capturing standard out and error with Process object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531068/powershell-capturing-standard-out-and-error-with-process-object)

But somehow code

```
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = "ipconfig.exe"
$pinfo.Arguments = "/all"
$pinfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.Verb = "RunAs"
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()
$stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
Write-Host "stdout: $stdout"
Write-Host "stderr: $stderr"
Write-Host "exit code: " + $p.ExitCode
```

keeps ignoring `$pinfo.Verb = "RunAs"` string and runs as regular user.
Please note, that I need to be able to run powershell commands with elevated privileges, not just programs like ping and calc.

Any ideas how to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: For using "RunAs" verb you need "UseShellExecute=$true".

Comment: Good point, @zett42, but if you do that, you won't be able to use and `.RedirectStandardOutput` and `.RedirectStandardError`

Comment: In short: It appears that for security reasons you cannot directly capture the output streams of an elevated process, and therefore need a workaround where you call a _shell_ as the elevated process and use that shell's redirection features to save the output streams to _files_.
See the linked duplicate for details.